# List Control

Tags: mfc

Does anyone know where I can get MFC ListView Control just like the one that FeedDemon uses ?
one which can be used to do grouping of items (FeedDemon).

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The native controls support grouping, although it is a relatively manual process.

In XP it does not support expand/collapse out of the box:
  [XP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/GroupListView.aspx)

In Vista you get expand/collapse: [Vista](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/CListCtrl_Grouping.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Ryan , for this.
it's nice.

Comment: The traditional way to convey that message is to click the little "up" arrow next to the answer.